# Sqlite: Create table with duplicate rows based on non primary key field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqllite table;

```
CREATE TABLE tmp2(
  id INT,
  account TEXT,
  name TEXT,
)
```

My table (Table tmp2) looks like:

```
 id  , account  , name

 1     A1        bob
 2     A2        dave,john,sally
 3     A3        tom
```

I need to create a new table (Table B), so that there is just 1 name/row:

```
 id  , account  , name

 1   A1        bob
 2   A2        dave
 2   A2        john
 2   A2        sally     
 3   A3        tom
```

duplicating all the other fields. Is this possible using sql ,given that the primary key cannot be duplicated? Also using sql how can I access the individual names in "dave, john, sally" ?

Comment: As long as the primary key is not just the `id` field, sure. You would probably make the primary key a composite key of `id, account, name`. A better, model-wise, solution would be to split this into two tables, one that lists the accounts and one that ties names to those accounts. It seems your table has two responsibilities here.

Comment: Are table tmp2 and A the same? if not please also show the structure of table A.

Comment: yes, fixed that, sorry

Comment: This would be easier to do in any scripting language.

Comment: What about the weird whitespaces/weird number of spaces between second "," and single name? Do you want them? Or would ", name" in all rows be OK?

Comment: Sorry, there is no white space. I'll fix it above, but "," is the element to split on.

Comment: I was going to use python to do this , but wondered if it would be possible in SQL alone, not knowing much SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SQLite solution (based on MCVE as shown at the end of this answer).

- make a recursive common table expression, `with singles(id, account, first, rest) as`
- from a `UNION ALL` of

  - id, account and
  - initially

    - first name in the list in tmp2, `substr(name, 0, instr(name||', ', ', '))`
    - rest of the list in tmp2, `substr(name, instr(name||', ', ', ')+2)`
  - recursively

    - pretty much the same, but from CTE singles
- from that CTE just select id, account and first name, `select id, account, first from singles`
- order by id and use special separator to match desired output,
  `order by id`, `.separator '   '`
- a little trick of appending ', ' first; this makes everything a single pattern repeated 1-N times

Code:

```
with singles(id, account, first, rest) as 
(    select id, 
            account,
            substr(name, 0, instr(name||', ', ', ')), 
            substr(name, instr(name||', ', ', ')+2) 
     from tmp2
 UNION
     select id, 
            account, 
            substr(rest, 0, instr(rest||', ', ', ')), 
            substr(rest, instr(rest||', ', ', ')+2) 
     from singles where rest!=''
) 
select id, account, first
from singles
order by id;
```

Output (with `.separator '   '`):

```
1   A1   Bob
2   A2   dave
2   A2   john
2   A2   sally
3   A3   tom
```

MCVE (sorry for the lower case initial typos...):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE tmp2(
  id INT,
  account TEXT,
  name TEXT);
INSERT INTO tmp2 VALUES(1,'A1','Bob');
INSERT INTO tmp2 VALUES(2,'A2','dave, john, sally');
INSERT INTO tmp2 VALUES(3,'A3','tom');
COMMIT;
```

Using SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28 18:48:43 on Windows 10

In case you are interested in the recursive CTEs with SQLite, I recommend this, which is my source of knowledge on them:
https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

By the way, I agree with Joey Pinto, using a decent database structure would have been better...

Comment: My pleasure, I always wanted to try something with a recursive CTE.

Comment: @user61629 I added my favorite link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to implement two tables like this

**Account Holders**

```
Account  Account Holder(Foreign Key to Users.user_id)
 A1,      1
 A2,      2
 A2,      3
 A2,      4    
 A3,      5
```

**Users**

```
User_id     UserName
1        Bob
2        Dave
3        John
4        Sally
5        Tom
```

To get all holders of account A2:

Select * from users where user_id in (Select Account_holder from Account_holders where Account='A2')

Comment: Thanks Joey, In my case, I'm dealing with a legacy system that has data in table A's format. I can't restructure the input.

Comment: So you are looking for an SQL query to convert table tmp2 into Table B directly?

Comment: I'm not a sql expert but if its possible, yes.